# Populate two columns based on different values of other two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
|ID|PREVIOUS |CURRENT|NEXT|
|--| --- | --- |---|
|1||A||
|1||B||
|2||C||
|2||D||
|2||E||
|2||F||
|3||G||
|4||H||
|4||I||
```

I want it to populate PREVIOUS and NEXT columns like this:

```
|ID|PREVIOUS |CURRENT|NEXT|
|--| --- | --- |---|
|1|nan|A|B|
|1|A|B|nan|
|2|nan|C|D|
|2|C|D|E|
|2|D|E|F|
|2|E|F|nan|
|3|nan|G|nan|
|4|nan|H|I|
|4|H|I|nan|
```

So for each unique ID I want to populate PREVIOUS and next columns based on the values of CURRENT column.

Until now I figured out how to do it if the df had only one type of ID (exept the case where there is no PREVIOUS and NEXT i.e ID=3) but I am struggling to generalize it for more ID-s.

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if i==0:
        df["PREVIOUS"].iloc[i] =  str(np.NaN)
        df["NEXT"].iloc[i] = df["CURRENT"].iloc[i+1]
    if i == (len(df)-1):
        df["NEXT"].iloc[i] = str(np.NaN)
        df["PREVIOUS"].iloc[i] = df["CURRENT"].iloc[i-1]
    if (i > 0) and (i < (len(df)-1)):
        df["PREVIOUS"].iloc[i] = df["CURRENT"].iloc[i-1]
        df["NEXT"].iloc[i] = df["CURRENT"].iloc[i+1]
```

I am guessing it should employe a groupby and size() but until now I couldn't achieve the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4], 'CURRENT':list('ABCDEFGHI')})
print(df)

from collections import defaultdict
valById = defaultdict(list)
df.apply(lambda x: valById[x['ID']].append(x['CURRENT']), axis = 1)
df = pd.DataFrame([{'ID':k, 'PREVIOUS': v[i-1] if i else np.nan, 'CURRENT': v[i], 'NEXT': v[i+1] if i+1 < len(v) else np.nan} for k, v in valById.items() for i in range(len(v))])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID CURRENT
0   1       A
1   1       B
2   2       C
3   2       D
4   2       E
5   2       F
6   3       G
7   4       H
8   4       I
   ID PREVIOUS CURRENT NEXT
0   1      NaN       A    B
1   1        A       B  NaN
2   2      NaN       C    D
3   2        C       D    E
4   2        D       E    F
5   2        E       F  NaN
6   3      NaN       G  NaN
7   4      NaN       H    I
8   4        H       I  NaN
```